# How do reset and replay quiz app when the game over in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a problem with my project, when I restart the quiz, the color of the previous answer and the icon remains there and does not disappear, so what is the way to solve the problem

my code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'question_model.dart';
import 'quiz_text.dart';
import 'result_page.dart';

class QuestionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuestionWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<QuestionWidget> createState() => _QuestionWidgetState();
}

class _QuestionWidgetState extends State<QuestionWidget> {
  late PageController _controller;
  int _indexQuestion = 1;
  int _score = 0;
  int timer = 10;
  int totalTime = 10;
  bool stopTimer = false;
  bool isClicked = false;
  bool isAlreadySelected = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    timerWatch();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timerWatch();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void timerWatch() async {
    const onesec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(onesec, (Timer t) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          if (timer < 1 || isClicked || stopTimer == true) {
            t.cancel();
          } else {
            timer = timer - 1;
          }
          totalTime = timer;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const QuizText(),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 32),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        " $_indexQuestion ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: _indexQuestion < questions.length ? 33 : 22,
                          color: _indexQuestion < questions.length
                              ? Colors.green
                              : Colors.amber,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "/",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        " ${questions.length}",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          color: Colors.amber,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  // timer text
                  Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
                    Text(
                      timer.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22,
                        color: timer < 5 ? Colors.red : Colors.amber,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 55,
                      height: 55,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        value: totalTime / 10,
                        valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.green),
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
                ],
              ),
              const Divider(
                thickness: 1,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: questions.length,
                  controller: _controller,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final question = questions[index];
                    return buildQuestion(question);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        floatingActionButton: //floatingNextButton()
            timer == 0 || isClicked
                ? floatingNextButton()
                : const SizedBox.shrink(),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      ),
    );
  }

  Column buildQuestion(Question question) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 32),
        Text(
          question.text,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 32),
        Expanded(
          child: OptionsWidget(
            question: question,
            onClickedOption: (option) {
              if (question.isLocked) {
                return;
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  question.isLocked = true;
                  question.selectedOption = option;
                });
                isClicked = question.isLocked;
                if (question.selectedOption!.isCorrect) {
                  _score++;
                }
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  FloatingActionButton floatingNextButton() {
    return FloatingActionButton.large(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        elevation: 11,
        onPressed: () {
          nextQuestion();
        },
        child: Text(_indexQuestion < questions.length ? 'Next' : 'Result'));
  }

  void nextQuestion() {
    timer = 10;
    stopTimer = false;
    if (isClicked) {
      setState(() {
        _indexQuestion++;
        isClicked = false;
        isAlreadySelected = false;
        timerWatch();
      });
      if (_indexQuestion < questions.length + 1) {
        _controller.nextPage(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 33),
          curve: Curves.easeInExpo,
        );
      } else {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Result(
                      score: _score, voidCallback: reset)));
      }
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Please select any option .. اختر اجابة '),
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      ));
    }
  }
  void reset() {
    setState(() {
      _indexQuestion = 0;
      _score = 0;
      isClicked = false;
      isAlreadySelected = false;
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}

class OptionsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Question question;
  final ValueChanged<Option> onClickedOption;

  const OptionsWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.question,
    required this.onClickedOption,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
        children: question.options
            .map((option) => buildOption(context, option))
            .toList(),
      ));
  Widget buildOption(BuildContext context, Option option) {
    final color = getColorForOption(option, question);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onClickedOption(option),
      child: Container(
        height: 55,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          border: Border.all(color: color, width: 2),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                option.text,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              getIconForOption(option, question)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Color getColorForOption(Option option, Question question) {
    final isSelected = option == question.selectedOption;
    if (question.isLocked) {
      if (isSelected) {
        return option.isCorrect ? Colors.green : Colors.red;
      } else if (option.isCorrect) {
        return Colors.green;
      }
    }
    return Colors.grey.shade300; 
  }

  Widget getIconForOption(Option option, Question question) {
    final isSelected = option == question.selectedOption;
    if (question.isLocked) {
      if (isSelected) {
        return option.isCorrect
            ? const Icon(
                Icons.check_circle,
                color: Colors.green,
              )
            : const Icon(
                Icons.cancel,
                color: Colors.red,
              );
      } else if (option.isCorrect) {
        return const Icon(
          Icons.check_circle,
          color: Colors.green,
        );
      }
    }
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}

lass Question {
  final String text;
  final List<Option> options;
  bool isLocked;
  Option? selectedOption;

  Question({
    required this.text,
    required this.options,
    this.isLocked = false,
    this.selectedOption,
  });
}

class Option {
  final String text;
  final bool isCorrect;

  Option({
    required this.text,
    required this.isCorrect,
  });
}

final questions = [
  Question(
    text: 'What is 2 + 2' , 
    options: [
      Option(text: '4', isCorrect: true),
      Option(text: '3', isCorrect: false),
      Option(text: '5', isCorrect: false),
      Option(text: '6', isCorrect: false),
    ],),
  Question(
    text: 'What is 3 + 5' , 
    options: [
      Option(text: '6', isCorrect: false),
      Option(text: '7', isCorrect: false),
      Option(text: '8', isCorrect: true),
      Option(text: '9', isCorrect: false),
    ],),
  Question(
    text: 'What is 20 + 2 - 8' , 
    options: [
      Option(text: '4', isCorrect: false),
      Option(text: '14', isCorrect: true),
      Option(text: '11', isCorrect: false),
      Option(text: '13', isCorrect: false),
    ],),
];
```

Result page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiz3/question_widget.dart';
import 'package:quiz3/quiz_homePage.dart';

import 'quiz_text.dart';

class Result extends StatelessWidget {
  const Result({super.key, required this.score, required this.voidCallback});
  final int score;
  final VoidCallback voidCallback;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Center(
              child: QuizText(),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 77),
            const Text(
              'Name : name',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 77),
            Text(
              '$score',
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 55,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 33),
            Text(
              '$score/ 10',
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 33,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 77),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const QuestionWidget()));
                  
                  voidCallback;
        
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 55, vertical: 14)),
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text('Replay',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 22),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const QuizHomePage()));
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 55, vertical: 14)),
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text('Exit',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do the reset but it didn't work, it resets every value but can't hide the color and icon option of the previous answer

[image]

Comment: I'd put everything related to game state into a single RiverPod Provider holding the "Game" object, and then use ref.invalidate when I wanted to start over.